# ASP.NET csharp view without razor and aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a SPA with ASP.NET MVC for back-end and i was quite curious - Is there any way to build view only using c# to generate my html without using any razor pages or aspx?

Comment: May I ask why would you like to build your views in pure C#? Apart from using content and returning everything as a string, which is really not something anyone would recommend, I don't really see how you could do that.

Comment: Why are you trying it? One of the first rules of coding is not trying to invent the wheel...

Comment: Well guys I'll be honest with you and i'm tell you that my boss need it. In matter of fact he has no experience in web developing and MVC model, but he has experience in Silverlight and he is thinking in way of Silverlight technology. He tries to use something in way that is not build to be use. I told him this a million times but yea, he is the boss.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by returning a `content`, more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Content(System.String))

Comment: Yea i told so i can do something like this. But i ask in the matter if someone find a better solution ^^

Comment: There is no nice solution for a nasty problem.